# How to override css for Dark/Light Mode Toggle?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am trying hard to use [W3Scholls Dark Mode Toggle](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_toggle_dark_mode) for my webiste but what happens is that the background of my website doesn't changes.

This is my [Test Websit Page](https://freeairdrop.io/airdrop/bannertest.html) in which only stars could change their colour after Toggle Button is clicked.

I would be grateful for helping me override the style for website Test Page.

Comment: You have styled elements on your website. So you have to specify elements which you want to change their styles.

Comment: Please post minimal code of website in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to understand that the W3Scholls example is just an example. your body's background is not showing so changing it won't show. if for example, you changed the background for the `about-area` div you will see it. you need to elaborate every style in every element you want to change and then connect it with the `dark-mode` selector.

example:

```
body.dark-mode .about-area {
    background: black;
}

body.dark-mode p {
    color: white;
}
```